# unable to get correct HTML response for "Myntra" website while using requests.get()

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping

I have come across a problem while scraping "myntra" website. I am trying to scrape prices and availability. when using requests.get(), I get the content of the website in localhost but can't get it in google colab. The response is <200> both times but getting a response of site maintenance HTML page in colab whereas everything is working fine under the local host. I really can't understand what's going on. I would be really thankful if anyone could help me out with this. Everything is working fine locally but not in server
[Myntra product link](https://www.myntra.com/jeans/levis/levis-512-men-black-slim-tapered-fit-mid-rise-clean-look-light-fade-stretchable-jeans/16612780/buy?utm_campaign=_3_&utm_medium=affiliate&utm_source=grabon)

My Code:

```
s=requests.session()
url="https://www.myntra.com/jeans/levis/levis-512-men-black-slim-tapered-fit-mid-rise-clean-look-light-fade-stretchable-jeans/16612780/buy?utm_campaign=_3_&utm_medium=affiliate&utm_source=grabon"
page=s.get(url)
page.content
```

Output:

```
b'<!doctype html> <html> <head>     <title>Site Maintenance</title>     <style type="text/css">body { text-align: center; padding: 150px; }h1 { font-size: 40px; }body { font: 16px Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #333; }#error { display: block; text-align: left; width: 650px; margin: 0 auto; }</style> </head> <body>     <div id="error">     <h1>Oops! Something went wrong</h1>     <div>         <hr>         <p>Please contact your administrator</p>     </div>     </div> </body> </html>'
```

getting correct content locally

Comment: Have you tried adding a header including user-agent to your session obj?

Comment: Yeah I used headers. It's working locally. The problem comes when I try the same in Google colab.

Answer (score 0):

This web use anti-bot security **Akamai Bot Manager**.
How to bypass **Akamai Bot Manager**?
In this case just adding **User-Agent it works**. User-agent's are used to indicate that you are using a real browser.
Also this site needs **javascript to render all content**, but you can find **script tag** that has one json with all info you need.

Here you have some working code:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

headers = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
}
src = requests.get(
    'https://www.myntra.com/jeans/levis/levis-512-men-black-slim-tapered-fit-mid-rise-clean-look-light-fade-stretchable-jeans/16612780/buy?utm_campaign=_3_&utm_medium=affiliate&utm_source=grabon',
    headers=headers)
result = src.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(result, 'html.parser')

scripts = soup.find_all('script')

for script in scripts:
    if "price" in script.text:
        json = json.loads(script.text.replace("\t", "").replace("\n", ""))
        print("Name: " + json["name"])
        print("Sku: " + json["sku"])
        print("Description: " + json["description"])
        print("Stock: " + json["offers"]["availability"])
        print("Price: " + json["offers"]["price"])
        break
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Name: Levis 512 Men Black Slim Tapered Fit Mid-Rise Clean Look Light Fade Stretchable Jeans
Sku: 16612780
Description: Levis 512 Men Black Slim Tapered Fit Mid-Rise Clean Look Light Fade Stretchable Jeans
Stock: InStock
Price: 3329
```

Comment: Yeah tried with the user-agent headers.but can't get the output in colab. Did you try this in google colab?

Comment: On getting correct response locally, i tried to make an api endpoint which returns price of the item, so i deployed it aws lambda.after deploying it, I was not able to get the correct output. So to check the errors I ran the same code in Google colab, then the above error is showing up and then I came to know that it's not working on server.

Comment: They block you by IP address, we don't know what are doing google colab and what IP address are using.

Comment: any solution for that?